# csrf token is missing while doing post in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework

while calling post it is say csrf token missing.I used Vuejs &drf how i will pass csrf token in Vue

```
function(){
     this.loading = true;
     this.$http.post('/get_books/', this.new_book).then(response=> 
     {this.getBooks();})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set csrf token using the global configurations

`Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = csrfToken`